# formatting error in a field models.DateField()

Tags: python, django, model, admin, datefield

I have a model in the models.py file of my django project, where a date field does not respect the format in the admin, where it appears as if it were a charField.

from django.db import models

class registro(models.Model):
fechaNacimiento = models.DateField()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0RGn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you, but I think you want something like that in the model too, to format like in admin

```
from django.db import models

class Registro(models.Model):
    fechaNacimiento = models.DateField()

    def fecha_formateada(self):
        return self.fechaNacimiento.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

Comment: Lo que busco es que mediante el campo DateField me de a elegir la fecha con un calendario que previamente aparecía pero en unas últimas pruebas no lo despliega.


what I am looking for is that when declaring a DateField field, it allows me to choose in the administrator page by calendar and not manually.

Comment: Please answer in English _only_.